# How do I solve OOM error when using tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building a data pipeline using tf.data.Dataset API but got an OOM error. Assume I already have `features` and `labels` in hand, which are 4D numpy arrays in the order of [N,H,W,C]. Here is how I create my `dataset` object:

```
batch_size = 100
num_samples = features.shape[0] # number of training samples

features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_size], name='features_placeholder')
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, label_count], name='labels_placeholder')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(num_samples)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
init_op = iterator.initializer
```

The reason I used `tf.placeholder` can be refered to [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays), which basically suggests defining `dataset` using `tf.placeholder` to save memory if the data are large numpy arrays(there are 54368 samples in my training dataset). The training part looks like:

```
for i in range(epoch):
    sess.run([init_op, optimizer], 
             feed_dict={features_placeholder:features, labels_placeholder:labels]}
```

But I got an error that says:

`OOM when allocating tensor with shape[54368,40,3,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc`

which, as I trace back, occurred at a `tf.layers.conv2d` layer defined in my model. How do I solve this OOM problem?

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller batch size?

Comment: You misplaced dataset.batch and shuffle. Also there's something wrong with the tensor size. Are you constructing dataset from a single numpy array?

Comment: @borarak By keeping the same batch size but feeding smaller arrays into `features_placeholder` and `labels_placeholder` there is no more error, so the batch size should not matter. However that means I can only read part of training data into `features` and `labels` instead of the whole dataset.

Comment: @Sharky Can you specify what's wrong with the tensor size? I am trying to construct a dataset using `tf.placeholder` with the same shape as `features` and `labels` except for rank 0(the number of data samples)

Comment: first dimension should be batch size,  not size of dataset

Answer (score 0):

In docs for `shuffle` it is written that `... fills a buffer with buffer_size elements ...` so in your case your dataset would take at least 54368*40*3*64*32*2 bits which is around 3.4GB. Just for the shuffle operation. Are you using 4GB gpu?

Another thing is that prefetch buffer_size should rather be bigger than 1. Why would you want to prefetch 1 element, maybe a batch or two?